# Vim zenburn doesn't work under screen in mac

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, gnu-screen

I'm trying to use zenburn on OSX under vim. However, whenever I use vim under screen, the background is black instead of grey. Are there color settings I need to set in screen?

Here's my screenrc:

```
vbell off
vbell_msg "Ring"

# detach on hangup
autodetach on

# don't display copyright page
startup_message off

# scroll back
defscrollback 10000

# setup the caption
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{-b gk}%-w%{+b kg}%50>%n %t%{-b gk}%+w %=%C%<"

# right/left bindings
bindkey "^[[c" next
bindkey "^[[d" prev
bindkey "^[[b" focus

# screen 256 color support
attrcolor b ".I"
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
defbce "on"

# Make terminal scrolling work properly with screen
termcapinfo xterm-256color|xterm-color|xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@

shell -${SHELL}
```

Comment: I see lots of settings, but no `term screen-256color`.  What $TERM are you using?

Comment: (I can't give a real answer because I'm away from my Mac to look at my screenrc, but I do have Zenburn and other 256 color schemes working properly under screen on OSX).

Comment: Ok, I was able to check my OSX screenrc. The only thing I have drastically different than you is `term xterm-256color` and `altscreen on`.  I don't have any specifics for termcapinfo, but those are probably not harmful as you have them.

Comment: In vim, try `:set background=dark` or `:set background=light` and see if this changes anything.

Comment: Also you can try this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim

Comment: I had to read this like 5 times before i realised you ment screen the programmer rather than literally under your screen. I was very intrigued.

Comment: I had an empty .screenrc and duplicated the problem.  Adding ```term xterm-256color``` and ```altscreen on``` to the .screenrc made no difference.  Could it be that we are running older versions of screen? I have: ```Screen version 4.00.03```